# Log level of HttpException in FastAPI for failed login

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, http-status-codes

In my FastAPI code, I have this:

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException

# ...
if not user:
    raise HTTPException(
        detail="User does not exist", status_code=HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND
    )
```

This is following [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code) recommendation to raise `HTTPException`. However, this will log every failed authentication attempt with a log level of **exception** in my logs, and thus trigger Sentry alerts etc.

Is this the expected behaviour? I think that failed logins are pretty common and expected (e.g. if the user misspells their name). Shouldn't they be logged as INFO? Is there a way to change the log level of the raised HTTPException (and should I do that)?

Comment: Basically, the logs you're seeing are generated by the Uvicorn server, not directly by your FastAPI application. However, this would be INFO as the default log level as well. I wonder how you get logs by ERROR level?